# SmsManager is not working in some devices (Marshmallow +)

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm developing android app that sends sms. I tried my app on android 4.3(Jelly bean) and it's working perfectly. But when I tried my app on Android marshmallow and newer my app crashes. Please check my codes below

```
private void sendSMS(String  phoneNumber, String  message) {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
    }else{
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

And also I add the permission on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Some articles stated that its because of the permission policy of newer android version but even I added the checking of permission it still not works. On first try app asks for permission then I allow it but still no sent sms. on 2nd try app crashes.

Comment: please post error log also

Comment: I can't find my error log on my android device sir. I'm trying it on actual device because emulator does not support sms

Comment: you can see in LogCat when you run from Android Studio right?

Comment: Android Studio's emulators do support SMS.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Anyway, you can still get logs from your device. Hook it up over USB.

Comment: Emulator has been supporting SMS, you need send sms/voice/call from Emulator control Please check the following link you will get more idea https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2vKw7pRHiQ

Comment: Some thing wrong happening with your permission, if you provide the code how your are managing permission we can check or please add your exception logs

Answer (score 0):

> Hope it finds you helpful... I am using it in my projects works from on all devices above 4.0 to 8.0

---

```
int CurrentSmsParts = 0;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
{

    int subscriptionId = SmsManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId();
    SmsManager MySmsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
    ArrayList<String> msgArray = MySmsManager.divideMessage(DefaultMsgTemplate);

    MySmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null,msgArray, null, null);
    CurrentSmsParts = msgArray.size();

    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nFOUND LOLLIPOP MR1 OR ABOVE...");
    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nDETECTED DEFAULT SMS SIM..."+subscriptionId);
    Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nSENT MSG USING SIM..."+subscriptionId);

  }
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
  {
       SmsManager MySmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
       ArrayList<String> msgArray = 
       MySmsManager.divideMessage(DefaultMsgTemplate);

       MySmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null,msgArray, null, null);
       CurrentSmsParts = msgArray.size();

       Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nFOUND BELOW LOLLIPOP MR1...");
       Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nDETECTED DEFAULT SMS SIM WHICHEVER AVAILABLE...");
       Log.d("SMS DETAILS : ", "\nSENT MSG USING SIM1 OR SIM2 WHICHEVER IS AVAILABLE...");
    }
```

---

> It is working code and tested on each emulator and actual devices too.. Hope it helps

Comment: Also whenever your app crashes, look for logcat without clicking close app on emulator, to keep exception msg alive in logcat, it shows you exact line of code which causes that exception, click on it, it moves your cursor to that file on that line causing the problem with details of crash or exception

Comment: I'm getting SMSManager returns RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE on Marshmallow OS when have dual SIM. kindly help me.